# Need help nesting code for easy duplication

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

My code below is working, but I want to know how I can pass the columns from the select as dynamic as possible. If I want to expand my code to include three or four queries on the page ideally I want to only duplicate the first three lines of code and the final one that calls the function.

If for example I had another query that called six columns from a different table, I'd just want to pass the columns in via function paramaters to the foreach result, instead of using the printf while naming each column.

I think that way the code can be more easily duplicated but am having trouble figuring that out.

Was also wondering if I can use the list/each like I have done with the titles on the result as well.

```
$showTeamInfoTitles = array("Team Id","Team Name","Captain");

$showTeamInfo = " SELECT teamid, teamname, captain FROM teams WHERE teamid= ?";

$whichteam=5;


function displayresults($query,$columntitles,$whichteam) {

    $dbh = database_connect();
    $sth = $dbh->prepare($query);
    $sth->bindValue(1, $whichteam, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $sth->execute();
    $result = $sth->fetchAll();


    echo "<table border='1'>";
    echo "<tr>";

    while (list($key, $value) = each($columntitles)) {
        echo "<th>" . $value . "</th>";
    } 

    echo "</tr>";
```

how do I nest this so I don't have to call the $value['captain'] for example

```
    foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
        printf("<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>", $value['teamid'], $value['teamname'], $value['captain'] );
    };

    echo "</table>";
}

// close the database connection
$dbh = null;

displayresults($showTeamInfo,$showTeamInfoTitles,$whichteam);
```

Another query perhaps would fetch the schedule for this team and display it on the same page:

```
SELECT hometeam, awayteam, gamedate, arena FROM schedule WHERE hometeam = ? OR awayteam = ?
```

So in the printf I'd have to hardcode each time for each column.

Comment: You have to provide an example of such a duplicate query, as nobody knows what you call a duplicate. **Not** an imaginary duplication right off your head but a real one you are goung to use.

Comment: Thanks, have added another example.

Comment: Well for this another query my setup is just perfectly fit. At least as long as a schedule can be displayed using the same format as a team table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two wrong premises that led you to this question:

1. You are going to display the query results within the same function that is getting them from database. It is considered unacceptable practice for many years already. You are supposed to use *templates* for the output.
2. You're under impression that all your queries will be as silly as just simple look-ups. In reality SQL is much more powerful and real queries going to be much more complex.

So, instead of a single function `fetchanddisplayresults()` you have to use two: `fetchresults()` and `displayresults()`. And although the latter one could be determined the way you want, the former one have to be more flexible, allowing any SQL to run.

Also you have to make sure that `database_connect()` doesn't connect to database every time it is called.

So it will be a code like this. For a query running function I would suggest a [PDO wrapper of mine](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/pdo_wrapper).

```
$teamTitles = array("Team Id","Team Name","Captain");
$whichteam = 5;
$sql = "SELECT teamid, teamname, captain FROM teams WHERE teamid= ?";
$teamData = DB::run($sql,[$whichteam])->fetchAll();

displayTable($teamTitles, $teamData);

function displayTable($titles, $data) {
?>
<table border='1'>
  <tr>
  <?php foreach($titles as $value)): ?>
    <th><?=$value?></th>
  <?php endforeach ?>
  </tr>
  <?php foreach($data as $row)): ?>
  <tr>
    <?php foreach($row as $value)): ?>
    <td><?=$value?></td>
    <?php endforeach ?>
  </tr>
  <?php endforeach ?>
</table>
<?
}
```

Comment: Yes I realize more complex db queries could exist, in this case though they will be simple selects. I will have a look at your wrapper and see if this can implement what I'm looking for. Thanks to for the suggestion of two separate functions, indeed these are the kind of things I'm trying to figure out now before a) making my code too verbose and b) making mistakes that should be avoided because I'm new at this.

Comment: Thanks for the help with the code. Made use of your wrapper.

Comment: Glad it helped. Feel free to ask any questions, I'll be glad to answer.